# Unique constraint violation during insert: why? (Oracle)

Tags: oracle, unique-constraint

I'm trying to create a new row in a table.  There are two constraints on the table -- one is on the key field (DB_ID), the other constrains a value to be one of several the the field ENV.  When I do an insert, I do not include the key field as one of the fields I'm trying to insert, yet I'm getting this error:

```
unique constraint (N390.PK_DB_ID) violated
```

Here's the SQL that causes the error:

```
insert into cmdb_db 
   (narrative_name, db_name, db_type, schema, node, env, server_id, state, path) 
values 
   ('Test Database', 'DB', 'TYPE', 'SCH', '', 'SB01', 381, 'TEST', '')
```

The only thing I've been able to turn up is the possibility that Oracle might be trying to assign an already in-use DB_ID if rows were inserted manually.  The data in this database was somehow restored/moved from a production database, but I don't have the details as to how that was done.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Presumably, since you're not providing a value for the `DB_ID` column, that value is being populated by a row-level before insert trigger defined on the table.  That trigger, presumably, is selecting the value from a sequence.

Since the data was moved (presumably recently) from the production database, my wager would be that when the data was copied, the sequence was not modified as well.  I would guess that the sequence is generating values that are much lower than the largest `DB_ID` that is currently in the table leading to the error.

You could confirm this suspicion by looking at the trigger to determine which sequence is being used and doing a

```
SELECT <<sequence name>>.nextval
  FROM dual
```

and comparing that to

```
SELECT MAX(db_id)
  FROM cmdb_db
```

If, as I suspect, the sequence is generating values that already exist in the database, you could increment the sequence until it was generating unused values or you could alter it to set the `INCREMENT` to something very large, get the nextval once, and set the `INCREMENT` back to 1.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are not providing a value for the primary key field DB_ID.  If that is a primary key, you must provide a unique value for that column.  The only way not to provide it would be to create a database trigger that, on insert, would provide a value, most likely derived from a sequence.

If this is a restoration from another database and there is a sequence on this new instance, it might be trying to reuse a value.  If the old data had unique keys from 1 - 1000 and your current sequence is at 500, it would be generating values that already exist.  If a sequence does exist for this table and it is trying to use it, you would need to reconcile the values in your table with the current value of the sequence.

You can use SEQUENCE_NAME.CURRVAL to see the current value of the sequence (if it exists of course)

Comment: My information on the database says that the key should be automatically generated when a new row is inserted -- that's why I don't provide value for DB_ID.  Further, this same technique works on other tables in the database which are similar -- they have an automatically generated ID key.

Comment: Are you able to query the data dictionary to see if the necessary triggers/sequences exist in the new environment?  Perhaps not everything was brought across from the old environment.

Answer (score 1):

Your error looks like you are duplicating an already existing Primary Key in your DB.  You should modify your sql code to implement its own primary key by using something like the IDENTITY keyword.

```
CREATE TABLE [DB] (
    [DBId] bigint NOT NULL IDENTITY,
    ...

    CONSTRAINT [DB_PK] PRIMARY KEY ([DB] ASC),

);
```

Comment: IDENTITY isn't a valid keyword in Oracle.

Comment: That is an invalid statement for Oracle

Comment: You, sir, are correct.  My solution works in SQL, not in Oracle.  If you wanted to duplicate SQL's Identity in Oracle, you would want to use Sequences [link](http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/sequences.php)  @Justin_Cave has a fine implementation in his answer.