# 00001. 00000 - "unique constraint (%s.%s) violated"

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have MAIN_TABLE, which holds 7 million records. I have to

1. keep last 3 months data In MAIN_TABLE
2. archive last 4 to 12 months data in  MAIN_TABLE_ARCHIVAL
3. purge all data older than 12 months

I created a stored procedure with a cursor to copy from MAIN_TABLE to MAIN_TABLE_ARCHIVAL. 
I have composite primary key(CONSTRAINT "PK_MAIN_TABLE" PRIMARY KEY ("SERVICE", "TR_SOURCE", "TR_ID")

While copying I am getting  00001. 00000 -  "unique constraint (%s.%s) violated" error even though i am not inserting any duplicate key but at the same time records are copied into MAIN_TABLE_ARCHIVE.

My code would look like (I have around 20 fields so I'm not pasting the whole code):

```
DECLARE
   c_id customers.id%type;
   c_name customers.name%type;
   c_addr customers.address%type;

   CURSOR c_customers is
    SELECT id, name, address FROM customers;
BEGIN
  OPEN c_customers;
  LOOP
    FETCH c_customers into c_id, c_name, c_addr;
    EXIT WHEN c_customers%notfound;
    dbms_output.put_line(c_id || ' ' || c_name || ' ' || c_addr);
    commit;
  END LOOP;
  CLOSE c_customers;
END;
/
```

I tried to debug, but no luck as I am new to PL/SQL. Can any one please tell me why it is happening? How should I implement the above assignment?

Answer (score 0):

To copy data from one table to another you don't need any cursor. You even don't need stored procedures. You could make this with one simple sql-statement:

```
insert into MAIN_TABLE_ARCHIVAL select * from MAIN_TABLE where <...your condition...>
```

To improve perfomance you could use "+append" hint.

Comment: Are you sure? Even for table with logging append puts data to the new extents and sometimes works much more faster then usual insert.

Comment: Most eficient solution for the task would use partitioning. If both table a partitioned by months, then moving data from one table to another could be made by exchanging of partitions (which excludes any data movement). But I think such solution is too cmplicate for novices.

Comment: MAIN_TABLE consists of around 8 million records. Will there be any performance issue if we use simple insert into -- select * from -- statement. I read somewhere about batch copying will increase the performance. And also can we implement all three 1)keep last 3 months data In MAIN_TABLE
2)archive last 4 to 12 months data in MAIN_TABLE_ARCHIVAL
3)purge all data older than 12 months by adding some conditions to the above statement??

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this: 
[Unique constraint violation during insert: why? (Oracle)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7571245/unique-constraint-violation-during-insert-why-oracle)

Compare the Start Value from your Sequence with MAX(ID) from you Table.

`SELECT MAX(ID_Column) FROM Schema.Table;
SELECT Schema.Table_Sequence.nextval from DUAL;`